# c#: Compare office documents and get just true/false results if files are identical

Tags: c#, compare, ms-office

I need to compare office files (doc, docx, xls, xlsx, ppt, pptx) and just get as a result ***a boolean value if 2 compared files are identical***.

I found a solution with generating result file from comparing of 2, but I don't need this.

```
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        wordApp.Visible = false;
        wordApp.DisplayAlerts = WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone;
        object wordTrue = (object)true;
        object wordFalse = (object)false;
        object fileToOpen = @"D:\Docs\1.docx";
        object missing = Type.Missing;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc1 = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref fileToOpen,
           ref missing, ref wordTrue, ref wordFalse, ref missing,
           ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
           ref missing, ref missing, ref wordTrue, ref missing,
           ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

        object fileToOpen1 = @"D:\Docs\3.docx";
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc2 = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref fileToOpen1,
            ref missing, ref wordTrue, ref wordFalse, ref missing,
            ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
            ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
            ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = wordApp.CompareDocuments(doc1, doc2, WdCompareDestination.wdCompareDestinationNew, WdGranularity.wdGranularityWordLevel,
            true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, "", false);
```

Is there any solution exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found for you:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = wordApp.CompareDocuments(doc1, doc2, WdCompareDestination.wdCompareDestinationNew, WdGranularity.wdGranularityWordLevel,
            true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, "", false);

bool anyChanges = doc.Revisions.Count > 0;
```

Comment: Glad to help you :)